# SelectedIndexChanged not working while RadioButtonList selected asp.net c#? autopostback also set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i've been struggling here for lot... kindly help..
below aspx page code...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="sing_group" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Single</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Group</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

my code behind code...

```
    protected void sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sing_group.SelectedValue == "0")
        {
            first_name.Enabled = true;
            last_name.Enabled = true;
            group_name.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            first_name.Enabled = false;
            last_name.Enabled = false;
            group_name.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is not working when you are in debug you go in sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged on change index ?

Comment: code looks right.Use debugger set breakpoints at `Page_load`, `sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this as well.. this will run for sure..

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="sing_group" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                       AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Single</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Group</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

Protected Void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e){
    sing_group.SelectedIndexChanged += sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
protected void sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (sing_group.SelectedValue == "0")
    {
        first_name.Enabled = true;
        last_name.Enabled = true;
        group_name.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        first_name.Enabled = false;
        last_name.Enabled = false;
        group_name.Enabled = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), the event name is OnSelectedIndexChanged
In your code it is all in small case.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're writing wrong code. Please, change your code.

Your code is:

```
onselectedindexchanged="sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

But should be:

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="sing_group_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

You can get output.